# How to search for 2 single quote signs ('') in a LIKE statement?

Tags: sql, exasol

I have a text field which I need to check if this char combination '' (not to be confused with ") appears anywhere in the column.

This SQL code

```
SELECT TEXTFIELD
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE TEXTFIELD LIKE '%''%'
```

returns text like

> BARN'S

which does not contain 2 single quote signs next to each other.

How can I filter correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes i.e.

```
SELECT TEXTFIELD
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE TEXTFIELD LIKE '%''''%'
```